# Write and Empty Temp Table into a HTML table in SQL Server

Tags: html, sql, sql-server, email

I'll be scheduling a SQL server code to output a HTML into an email daily, sometimes this table might have no rows. I still want the code to run and send the email but saying "No Data" or something along those lines.

Is this possible? If so could someone show some example code? I'm assuming I'll need to change the From bit of the code, i.e.

```
CAST(( select td =col1,'', td=col2,''
from #TempTable1
Order by 1
For XML PATH ('tr'),TYPE
) AS NVARCHAR(MAX) ) +
```

etc....

So to clarify: My question is how do I do a "conditional" from statement, i.e. if #TempTable1 has data then enter #TempTable1 if not then say "No Data".

Thanks @SeanLange for pointing out my questions wasn't clear.

Comment: Not really sure what your question is here. And don't order by ordinal position, you should use the column name.

Comment: @SeanLange sorry if not clear. My question is how do I do a "conditional" from, i.e. if #TempTable1 has data then enter this if not then say "No Data".

Comment: Don't do that kind of thing in your query at all if the best way. Have your logic do that. If the query returns no rows then simply send the string you want, otherwise build your html table and send that.

Comment: @SeanLange if you could share some example logic on how to do that then it would solve this question for me? I'm not sure how to get my logic to do this.

Comment: You are trying to hard here. The logic that sends your email is what you need to adjust. Run your query, if it returns no rows than you send the "No Data". And you can't have a table with no rows contain data.

Comment: @SeanLange I'm not going to be running this manually every day, once set up it will run automatically every morning that's why I want it to be in the logic. Hope that makes sense, sorry I'm not the best at explaining things.

Comment: I was not assuming you were doing this manually but not sure what that has to do with the question.

Comment: @SeanLange I think there's a lot of confusion here. If you know how to have the output of the HTML show the rows if they exist and show "No Data" if they don't then please share the code below as an answer to the question. If you don't know how to do this please let me know and I can try other channels.

Comment: You haven't shown us the code where you get your data. This really is simple, I think you are overthinking this. Are you trying to do this 100% with t-sql or some programming language?

Comment: The data comes from #TempTable1 as mentioned sometimes this is completely empty. It's all in T-sql

Comment: I can't see your screen or read your mind but you are asking for others to provide detailed code. Make it easy for others to help you. How are you sending the email? Where is the full query? You know the things needed to offer help for this type of thing.

Comment: I've had an answer that works below, so I think it must be quite clear what I was asking for. Thank you for trying to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check before you get the data from your table whether the table has data in it or not. I would do something like this:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM "YourTable") 
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM "YourTable"
END ELSE BEGIN
    SELECT 'No Data'
END
```

EDIT:

```
DECLARE @temp NVARCHAR(MAX) = CAST(( select td =col1,'', td=col2,''
    from #TempTable1
    Order by 1
    For XML PATH ('tr'),TYPE
    ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX) )

IF(LEN(@temp) = 0)
BEGIN
    SELECT 'No Data'
END ELSE BEGIN
    SELECT @temp
END
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this! How would I include this in the HTML code? Does it go between the cast and the select?